# Ignoring certain files in project structure(custom project type)

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I'm currently creating a project type in Netbeans.  I followed the basic tutorial but added a few things.

This is the logical view

```
    public org.openide.nodes.Node createLogicalView() {
        FileObject root = project.getProjectDirectory();
        DataFolder findFolder = DataFolder.findFolder( root );
        Node node = findFolder.getNodeDelegate();


        return new TextNode( node, project );
}
```

Basically the root is the project folder.

This is my filter node.

```
private static final class TextNode extends FilterNode {

    final NodeJSProject project;

    public TextNode( Node node, NodeJSProject project ) {

        super( node, new NodeJSProjectNode( node ),
                new ProxyLookup( new Lookup[]{
                    Lookups.singleton( project ),
                    node.getLookup()
                } ) );

        this.project = project;
    }
```

And my custom override for filter node.

```
public static class NodeJSProjectNode extends FilterNode.Children {

        public NodeJSProjectNode( Node node ) {
            super( node );
        }

        @Override
        protected Node[] createNodes( Node key ) {
//key.getName() only returning root objects.  No children
            if ( key.getName().startsWith( "." ) ) {
                return new Node[]{};
            }
            return new Node[]{ copyNode( key ) };
        }
    }
```

Basically I'm trying to ignore hidden files.  I was thinking this was done by the IDE already but I guess not.  The code I currently have works for the the root directory.  It will not add .DS_Store, .git, etc.  I'm trying to ignore all folders/files in the child directories.  I'm not sure how this is done using the createNodes method.  The only key's that seem to be coming in are the root nodes/files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been following same tutorial and I have been able to realise a result that suits my special case; in my project type I want to see only 'xlsx' or 'xls' or 'txt' file types.

But I can see you took a different turn than the tutorial directs. Here's your constructor for TextNode

```
super( node, new NodeJSProjectNode( node ),
            new ProxyLookup( new Lookup[]{
                Lookups.singleton( project ),
                node.getLookup()
            } ) );
```

This is the tutorial's template:

```
super(node,
        NodeFactorySupport.createCompositeChildren(
                project, 
                "Projects/org-customer-project/Nodes"),
        // new FilterNode.Children(node),
        new ProxyLookup(
        new Lookup[]{
            Lookups.singleton(project),
            node.getLookup()
        }));
```

If you were to follow the tutorial as it goes, I believe I can help.